# Pdf engine "CakePdf.Dompdf" not found in CakePHP 3

Tags: pdf, cakephp, dompdf

I have used CakePdf.Dompdf for generating PDF file. It's working for localhost; then I upload on server, but it's not working.

Then I install Composer on live server and fire all commands with regards to dompdf, but still not working.

Comment: It is difficult to say what your problem is, since your post is rather light on detail. Have you tried regenerating your autoloaders on the server? `composer dumpautoload`.

Comment: May be your autoload issue.

Comment: The engine is called `DomPdf`, with an uppercase `P`, not a lowercase `p`. Your local filesystem is case insensitive, the one on your server isn't, hence no matching file can be found as it uses an uppercase `P`.